# Extent reports failing the second time. Unable to reproduce in a small project

Tags: freemarker, extentreports, selenium-extent-report, extent

Can someone give me an idea of what must be happening in the second iteration of an execution when extent reports fail with the below error? For the first iteration, the report is created absolutely fine. When I create another report(at same or another path) on the same JVM instance, this issue is observed:

```
SEVERE: An exception occurred
FreeMarker template error:
No compatible overloaded variation was found; declared parameter types and argument value types mismatch.
The FTL type of the argument values were: extended_hash+string (com.aventstack.extentreports.Status wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel).
The Java type of the argument values were: com.aventstack.extentreports.Status.
The matching overload was searched among these members:
    com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.BasicFileReporter.containsStatus(String),
    com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.BasicFileReporter.containsStatus(com.aventstack.extentreports.Status)

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #if report.containsStatus(Status.PASS)  [in template "spark/partials/test.ftl" at line 17, column 49]
    - Reached through: #include "partials/test.ftl"  [in template "spark/spark.spa.ftl" at line 27, column 21]
----
```

No error is observed during the first execution. I have tried the following:

1. Removed all the ExtentTest.log() methods so that there is no Pass/Fail of the steps
2. Updated FreeMarker jar to version 2.3.30
3. Check with Extent version 4.1.5